# Best framework for targetting a wide range of mobile devices

Tags: mobile, frameworks, client-server, bluetooth, mobile-phones

I'm trying to build a mobile application on a client-server model where clients are people's mobile devices and the server is a PC - all connecting over bluetooth.

I'm expecting the client to be very thin - just enough to establish communications, display some text, and relay user input.

What's the best framework to develop in? I want the maximum possible device compatibility (so for example not just series 60 capabale devices) as opposed to cool features - but the ability to scale easily to colour devices or ones with higher dispaly resolutions would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current mobile space, largest installed base + limited functionality = use JavaME. See http://java.sun.com and the the stackoverflow j2me and javame tags.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way might be to write MIDP application that uses [Bluetooth API.](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/bluetooth2/) That covers widest range of devices with least effort.